# Two computers - Same Net work - can't open XPages db directly on one but can on the other

Tags: windows, xpages

This is related to a previous question:

[Getting the Server Name from the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620094/getting-the-server-name-from-the-session)

I have two laptops connected to the same server, with the same connection documents on both. I I  and select the server say Development I get a list of all of the folders and files on both computers. If I select a DB that opens in a standard Notes Client (Not XPages) on either the DB opens correctly. However, if I select a DB that opens in XPages it fails on one but works fine on the other. Logged in as the same user in both cases. I have looked through the Notes.ini on both and can't see anything unusual. So I suspect that there is some Windows or Notes or server setting somewhere that is different but have no idea where. Probably obvious but I can't see it. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: The first thing I would check is the Windows Firewall settings on both clients.

Comment: What are the Notes Client versions involved? Does it throw an Error 500? If so, check IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder in notes/data for xpages_... files. Also Help > Support > Log and Help > Support > Trace will give info.

Comment: @Paul - the one that works is 8.5.3 and the one that does not is 9.0 In fact it does not appear to even get to the point of opening the Db it is as if it can't find it. It starts with a message opening XPages screen then goes to Yahoo search with the that it is trying to open:
development/XPages/XpagesApprovalMaster.nsf/xpWFSDemo.xsp?xspRunningContext=Notes

Comment: Plus windows Firewall is turned off on both computers. The strange thing is that standard Notes Client databases open fine. If I select an XPage in designer and say open in client it opens it but treats it as if opened locally session.getServerName() returns null - if I select the application and say open in client it fails. 
Very strange.

Comment: and you don't happend to have a local replica on one of the laptops? does the database require extension library?

Comment: Opening it from Notes will open it on server, if "Run on Server" is selected on Database Launch tab. I would expect that previewing from Designer will always run it locally, because you're not launching the database, you're previewing a design element.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to run the XPages app on server. On 8.5.3 that's not available so it will just run locally. On 9.0.x it will try to run on server, but using www.myServerCommonName.com. You need to add an entry in the Notes Preferences on the XPages Performance Tab, to tell it to open the database on server and to use a specific host name. It's well documented in Mastering XPages (I hit the same problem and referred to that.)

Comment: I did that but it still does not work must be something in the windows settings, really strange.

Comment: If it's still going to a Yahoo page, it's trying to launch on server, but the XPages Performance Tab settings aren't correct. I'm not aware of any settings outside Notes that could affect it. There is a new ECL setting for running Java code, but that would throw a security error rather than redirecting to Yahoo. The 8.5.3 client is not going to be a useful comparison I'm afraid.